# Python: Can you extend an array on each iteration using glob (or similar) to read in files from a directory

Tags: arrays, file, python-3.x, glob, with-statement

Is there a way to extend an array that stores data from a file on each iteration of a `for`-loop and `with` command combo, using `glob`. Currently, I have something like

```
import glob
from myfnc import func


for filename in glob.glob('*.dta'):
    with open(filename,'rb') as thefile:

        fileHead, data = func(thefile)
```

where `func` is defined in another script `myfnc`. What this does is on each iteration in the directory, stores the data from each file in `fileHead` and `data` (as arrays), erasing whatever was there on the previous iteration. What I need is something that will extend each array on each pass. Is there a nice way to do this? It doesn't need to be a for-loop, with combo. That is just how I am reading in all files from the directory.

I thought of initializing the arrays beforehand and then try extending them after the `with` is done on one pass, but it was giving me some kind of error with the `extend` command. With the error, the code would look like

```
import glob
from myfnc import func

fileHead, data = [0]*2


for filename in glob.glob('*.dta'):
    with open(filename,'rb') as thefile:

        fileHeadExtend, dataExtend = func(thefile)

    fileHead.extend(fileHeadExtend)
    data.extend(dataExtend)
```

So, the issue that it has is `fileHead` and `data` are both initialized but as int's. However, I don't want want to initialize the arrays to so many zeros. There should not be any arbitrary values in there to begin with. So, that is where issue is lying for this.

Comment: Add the Python error message to your question.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: Now you need to figure out which variable is an `int`.

Comment: Post the **entire** error message in the question, add the traceback as well!

Comment: although it seems a bit obvious... `fileHead, data = [0]*2
` sets both `fileHead` and `data` to the integer 0 and then you try to extend both of them... they are both 0, how are you extending 0?!?

Comment: Jeepers. How do you pronouce Tadhg?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I had assumed it was initializing two arrays, both to one element of zero. I went back to see if it would do it if I had separately initialized them as `fileHead  =[0]` and `data = [0]` which did work. Of course, I would had to have gone back later and remove the that first element after the data reading was done.

Comment: @Lou `fileHead, data = [0] , [0]` would do that, `[0]*2` make the list `[0,0]` and then unpacks the two elements to the two variables

Comment: @DavidCullen, [Taig or Teague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadhg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
import glob
from myfnc import func

fileHead = list()
data = list()

for filename in glob.glob('*.dta'):
    with open(filename,'rb') as thefile:
        fileHeadExtend, dataExtend = func(thefile)
    fileHead.extend(fileHeadExtend)
    data.extend(dataExtend)
```